Retrieve values from a list based on a larger or smaller list Python
My code isn't working as expected. I've tried a few different approaches, and I'm currently working on one that seems like it should work to me... I have a conditional structure that basically goes like this:

If the interval is between bin_start and bin_end
append to the interval
If the interval is outside bin_start and bin_end
continue (that interval will be discarded)
Else: If part is within bin_start and bin_end, I want to retrieve only what is included between them

for bin_start,bin_end in bins_list:
    for interval in exons_array:
        if bin_start >= interval[0] and bin_end <= interval[1]:
            valid_interval.append((bin_start, bin_end))
        if (bin_start < interval[0] and bin_end < interval[0]) or (bin_start > interval[1] and bin_end > interval[1]):
            continue 
        else:
            if bin_end > interval[1]:
                bin_end = interval[1]
            if bin_start < interval[0]:
                bin_start = interval[0]
            valid_interval.append((bin_start, bin_end))

I believe the issue lies precisely in this "else" part. A simple example for the else: I have two lists, [0,10] and [6,12]; this else should return [6,10].
Real problem data:
exons_array = [[7669608, 7669690], [7670608, 7670715], [7673218, 7673266], [7673306, 7673339], [7673534, 7673608], [7673700, 7673837], [7674180, 7674290], [7674858, 7674971], [7675052, 7675236], [7675993, 7676272], [7676381, 7676403], [7676520, 7676594]]

bins_list = [(7669608, 7670307), (7670307, 7671006), (7671006, 7671705), (7671705, 7672404), (7672404, 7673103), (7673103, 7673802), (7673802, 7674501), (7674501, 7675200), (7675200, 7675899), (7675899, 7676598)]

The code runs to completion, but the result is incorrect. Output example:
7669608 7670307 -> exons_array
7669608 7669690 -> bins_list
[] -> valid_interval

It should append valid_interval with 7669608 7669690 since exons_array is larger.

I can't reproduce your problem. Running your code with the example input exons_array = [[0, 10]] and bins_list = [(6, 12)] gives the expected valid_interval = [(6, 10)]. Running the code with your "real problem data" gives [(7669608, 7669690),  (7670608, 7670715),  (7673218, 7673266),  (7673802, 7673837),  (7674858, 7674971),  (7675200, 7675236),  (7675993, 7676272)], which seems correct at first glance -- the (7669608, 7669690) interval you expect is the first element of the list

I think you want to first exclude a bin/exon pair that don't overlap then for those that do, you want to find the minimum intersection between the ranges.
exons_array = [[7669608, 7670307]]
bins_list =   [[7669608, 7669690]]
valid_interval = []
for exon_start, exon_end in exons_array:
    for bin_start, bin_end in bins_list:
        ## -------------------
        ## this exon falls outside this bin
        ## -------------------
        if bin_start > exon_end or bin_end < exon_start:
            continue
        ## -------------------

        ## -------------------
        ## this exon is (partially) in this bin
        ## -------------------
        valid_interval.append((max(exon_start, bin_start), min(exon_end, bin_end)))
        ## -------------------

        ## -------------------
        ## we binned this exon so switch to the next one.
        ## -------------------
        break
        ## -------------------

print(valid_interval)

Giving you:
[(7669608, 7669690)]


here's some of my code used in advent of code 2023
source
def intersect(l1, l2):
    min_intersect = max(l1[0],l2[0]) # lower bound of intersect
    max_intersect = min(l1[1],l2[1]) #upper bound of intersect
    if min_intersect>max_intersect:
        return tuple() #same number intersect still included
    return (min_intersect,max_intersect)

for x,y in zip(exons_array, bins_list):
    print(intersect(x,y))

your first case seems to return the right values (excuse me if i'm running the intersections incorrectly); an empty tuple is returned if no intersect exists, in that case you should filter out that tuple

For the example code I provided, where would your addition go? I tested it isolated in a Jupyter notebook and liked the result, but I wanted to test it integrated into the code. I tried a few ways, but I ran into errors. Can I place it inside the else statement, or would I have to adapt the entire code for this function?

you could just use list comprehension and filter list(filter(lambda x: x!=tuple(),[intersect(x,y) for x,y in zip(exons_array,bins_list)])) or put it in the for loop up above (if result is not tuple() -> valid_interval.append(result))
